# create multiple rows from one row in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In dataframe or parquet file in spark it has input data like below and It should generate multiple rows from one row using spark scala.
Input:

```
Id    PersonName  Dept  year  Language
1     David       501   2018  English
2     Nancy       501   2018  English 
3     Shyam       502   2018  Hindi
```

Output in a file or dataframe should be like below

```
1  David 
1  501   2018 
1  David English
2  Nancy 
2  501   2018 
2  Nancy English 
3  Shyam
3  502  2018
3  Nancy Hindi
```

Comment: What are the meanings/names of the columns in the expected result? A DataFrame cannot have records with different schemas, it has one schema that must apply to _all_ records. It seems like your requirement contradicts this. What are you trying to achieve with this heterogeneous DataFrame?  Also - you're being downvoted because you didn't show any effort of solving this yourself - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

@Arvy 
I am not sure why you would want to do this. Your table should have consistent columns. However, this can be done with a simple select and union.

*Pyspark*

Create Dataframe:

```
    values = [
        (1, "David", 501, 2018, "English"),
        (2, "Nancy", 501, 2018, "English"),
        (3, "Shyam", 502, 2018, "Hindu"),
    ] 

    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values, ['Id', 'PersonName', 'Dept', 'year', 'Language'])
```

Create New Dataframe:

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
    col_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
    df1 = df.select('ID', 'Dept', 'year').toDF(*col_names)
    df2 = df.select('ID', 'PersonName', 'Language').toDF(*col_names)
    df3 = df.select('ID', 'PersonName').withColumn('a', lit('')).toDF(*col_names)

    df_random = df1.union(df2).union(df3).orderBy('col1')
    df_random.show()
```

*Scala*

Create New DataFrame:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions, Column, DataFrame, SQLContext}
    val col_names = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
    val df1 = df.select("ID", "Dept", "year").toDF(col_names: _*)
    val df2 = df.select("ID", "PersonName", "Language").toDF(col_names: _*)
    val df3 = df.select("ID", "PersonName").withColumn("a", lit("")).toDF(col_names: _*)

    val df_random = df1.union(df2).union(df3).orderBy("col1")
    df_random.show()
```